# jQueryUI linked datepicker (Start-End date): Enddate reads dd/mm/yy format as mm/dd/yy

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a linked jQuery datepicker, with EndDate constrained to be higher (closer) than StartDate. Dates are in dd/mm/yy format. The problem I am facing is that once I click the StartDate (say March 5 as 05/03/2017), the second picker starts at May 03. Has anyone encountered this behaviour before? Should I remove format specs in EndDate?
Output here: [image: EndDate is messed] and code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".datepickerStart").datepicker({
constrainInput: true,
showAnim: "slideDown",
dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
firstDay: 1,
numberOfMonths: 1,
onClose: function (selectedDate, obj) {
    var index = obj.input.data("index");
    $(".datepickerEnd[data-index="+index+"]").datepicker("option", "minDate", new Date(selectedDate));
    if(index == 0){
        $(".datepickerStart[data-index=1],.datepickerEnd[data-index=1]").datepicker("option", "maxDate", new Date(selectedDate))}}

    });

var currentDate = new Date();
var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
var pastYear = currentYear - 80;
var pastDate = new Date(pastYear+"/01/01");

$(".datepickerStart[data-index=1]").datepicker("option", "minDate", pastDate);

$(".datepickerStart[data-index=1]").datepicker( "setDate", pastDate);

$(".datepickerEnd").datepicker({
    constrainInput: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    changeYear: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your problems is that `new Date('01/02/03')` parses date using mm/dd/yyyy date format.

Replace all your `new Date(something)` to `$.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', something)`.